# Organizing files in Cocos2d

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have just started learning Cocos2d using the great tutorials 
[Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/457/intro-to-box2d-with-cocos2d-tutorial-bouncing-balls) has produced. However I'm getting to a point where my HelloWorldScene main file is getting a little large.

I would like to be able to sort sprite generation methods into one file, misc. methods into another and so on, leaving me with the core level files containing the different scenes and init methods.

Is it possible to copy methods over to a new .m file and bring them into the HelloWorldScene.m when I need them?

How do you organize your game files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I highly recommend layering your game. It keeps it organised and neater, reducing the amount of code in any one file.

Within cocos2d, there are 3 classes you should take note of to achieve this:
CCDirector, CCScene, CCLayer.

What you can do is, create multiple layers within a single scene (GameScene).Eg: 
Have a HUD, Game Interface, Background and Foreground.

These can all be split into their separate CCLayers and added together within the CCScene.

So now you have split HelloWorld.m into:
GameScene.m
HudLayer.m
GameInterfaceLayer.m
Background.m
Forground.m

After importing all the h files into your GameScene.h, You can then add each Layer to the scene as Follows:

```
@implementation GameScene
+(CCScene){

HudLayer *hud = [HudLayer node];
[self addChild: hud z:3];

GameInterfaceLayer *game = [GameInterfaceLayer node];
[self addChild: game z:1];
...} etc
@end
```

Once you do this, if you dont change your AppDelegate, your CCDirector will give you an error. CCDirector basically dictates which Scene is loaded.
Change this to point to your GameScene.

You can visualise: the Director of the Movie, Filming a Scene, filled with many Layers.

Comment: Thank you, really made things clear for me. One question though - when you say change the app delegate, is that simply so GameScene runs on load?

Comment: Yea, the ccdirector will attempt to load the scene (by default) in the helloworld implementation. Because your removed it and put it in the newly created gamescene, you need to point the appdelegate to the new location. Did you get it running?

Comment: Yes I did :) many thanks. What I ended up doing was using the main GameScene.m file to hold all the core stuff like hud and game logic then created separate files for friendly sprites, enemy sprites, menu screen etc. Working very well so far!